How to view stdout in ida debugger
I have a program that prints to stdout.
I've stepped through the print calls with the debugger in ida-free but I can't find a view where I can see that output.

Unfortunately you are unable to view the stdout output in IDA Free like you might be able to in other IDEs. There would be plugins available in IDA Pro that would allow you to do this. Another option is to use the command line to run your program, a different IDE, or an external debugger for running. You can still use IDA Free for editing if you'd like. Lastly if you'd like to keep your entire workflow inside of IDA Free, then you can optionally redirect the output of stdout into a text file. Use freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);  (for C) at the beginning of your file to redirect normal stdout output to a file called "output.txt". You can then open it and read the output after every time you run the program.
